# How do i set the type of this state in my component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How do i set the type of this state in my component

---

```
  state: any = {
      profile: {
            details: any: {
            name: any: '',
            email: any: '',
            age: any: '',
            cellNumber: any: '',
          }
      }
  }
```

---

```
class NewNoteForm extends Component<props> {

  static defaultProps = {profileStore:{}}

  state = {
      profile: {
            details: {
            name: '',
            email: '',
            age: '',
            cellNumber: '',
          }
      }
  }
}


 interface IDetails
{
    name: string;
    email: string;
    age: number;
    cellNumber: number;
}

interface IProfile
{
    details: IDetails;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an interface for the state and use it when you define the class.

**Example**

```
interface NewNoteFormProps {}
interface NewNoteFormState {
  profile: {
    details: {
      name: string,
      email: string,
      age: string,
      cellNumber: string
    }
  };
}

class NewNoteForm extends Component<NewNoteFormProps, NewNoteFormState> {
  state = {
    profile: {
      details: {
        name: "",
        email: "",
        age: "",
        cellNumber: ""
      }
    }
  };

  render() {
    // ...
  }
}
```